# Dynamic Laravel Socialite Configurations

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

I need to configure my providers dynamically.

> ```
> $config = [
>     'client_id' = 'xxxxxxx',
>     'client_token' = 'xxxxxxx',
>     'redirect' = 'http://example.com/'
> ];
> return Socialite::with($provider)->setConfig($config)->redirect();
> ```

But unfortunately there is no function setConfig.

I need to set provider, client_id, client_secret and redirect dynamically

Is there any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Also please consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399021/socialite-google-redirect-uri-mismatch while changing url dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the Socialite `buildProvider` method like:

```
$config = [
    'client_id'    = 'xxxxxxx',
    'client_token' = 'xxxxxxx',
    'redirect'     = 'http://example.com/'
];

return Socialite::buildProvider(\Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider::class, $config);
```

Where `\Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider::class` would be swapped with your service (if different) as provided in either folder `One`/`Two` in https://github.com/laravel/socialite/tree/2.0/src

Comment: And one more, I do not understand how can I change \Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider::class services, for example if I have included additional instagram provider... Could you explain?

Comment: You can use the following package for the Instagram provider :) 
http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/instagram/

Comment: I see, it works. And I got new problem, when I set \Laravel\Socialite\One\TwitterProvider::class

Comment: sorry
I see, it works. And I got new problem, when I set \Laravel\Socialite\One\TwitterProvider::class - it returns the error "Type error: Argument 2 passed to Laravel\Socialite\One\AbstractProvider::__construct() must be an instance of League\OAuth1\Client\Server\Server, string given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/my-project/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/SocialiteManager.php on line 92"
And \Laravel\Socialite\One\BitbucketProvider::class the same error

Comment: this is not working when call callback ,it gives unauthrized 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following service provider in order to automatically fill in the `redirect` for each provider where it's empty.

It could be modified to update your configuration on the fly. It depends exactly what you're trying to do I suppose.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SocialServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        collect(config('services'))
            ->only(config('social.providers'))
            ->reject(function($config) {
                return array_get($config, 'redirect', false);
            })
            ->each(function($config, $key) {
                $url = url("login/{$key}/callback", [], true);

                config(["services.{$key}.redirect" => $url]);
            });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help if anyone still faces the problem
you can set the Redirect Url manually

```php
    $driver = Socialite::driver('google');
    $driver->redirectUrl('your-custom-url');
```