# Socialite Google redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: laravel, google-plus, laravel-socialite

I am trying to login with google using socialite , my facebook login works fine so the problem in my google app, any help!!!

```
 'google' => [
    'client_id' =>      'app-key',
    'client_secret' =>  'app-secret',
    'redirect' =>       'http://www.shoptizer.com/callback/google',
],
```

[image: google login Credentials]

Comment: all your authorized redirect url's registered with https in google. Do you have any https redirection? Because, in your config there is http based callback url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this link https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-google-login.html

From this tutorial:

> Occasionally it happens that google require some time to apply client configuration If you get an error message redirect_uri_missmatch wait couple of minutes and it should work normally.

Also change the redirect uri by:

```
'google' => [
   'client_id' =>      'app-key',
   'client_secret' =>  'app-secret',
   'redirect' =>       'https://www.shoptizer.com/callback/google',
],
```

If your app is provided by https you must match your http scheme on google api and on your redirect callback.

Comment: I am waiting more than 2 hours now

Comment: thanks that was the mistake I had to change it to https

Answer (score 6):

Also one more point to remember that Socialite also gives uri_mismatch_error even when your redirects are correctly defined in google console but you dynamically changed the redirectUrl through

```
return Socialite::with('google')->redirectUrl($redirect_url)->redirect();
```

So plz take care that you should also need to define while receiving the response

```
Socialite::driver('google')->redirectUrl($redirect_url)->stateless()->user();
```

where $redirect_url is your custom redirect url.
After google redirects you to correct place, but even then Socialite checks it at its end.

Comment: Very good point! This was what I needed.

Also note that you should use the `->redirectUrl()` method, and not the `->with(['redirect_uri' => '...'])` one, as the second one still causes the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the default url, you must change it on two occasions: before the redirect and before getting the user data.

Do not do this:

```
return Socialite::driver('google')->redirectUrl($yourredirecturl)->redirect();
```

Do it:

```
config()->set('services.google.redirect', $yourredirecturl);
return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
```

And when accessing user data, do this:

```
config()->set('services.google.redirect', $yourredirecturl);
$user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
```